# mysql WHERE один столбец IN (SELECT два столбца)

Tags: mysql

Всем привет! Сейчас изучаю sql, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть 3 таблицы:

1. photos - таблица с ID картинок (которые надо получить в финале)
2. tags- таблица с именем (tag_name) и ID уникальных тегов
3. tags_rel - таблица с отношениями photo_id -> tag_id

Делаю поиск по тегам. Пример: man, horse, riding и мне необходимо вывести фотографии по количеству теговвстречающихся у этой фотографии.

```
SELECT id FROM photos WHERE id IN (SELECT photo_id FROM tags_rel WHERE tag_id in ( SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag_name='man' OR tag_name='riding' OR tag_name='horse') GROUP BY photo_id ORDER BY COUNT(photo_id) DESC)
```

Данный запрос не сортирует по количеству. С этим отлично справляется запрос:

```
SELECT photo_id, COUNT(*) FROM tags_rel WHERE tag_id in ( SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag_name='man' OR tag_name='riding' OR tag_name='horse') GROUP BY photo_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Но если к нему подставить

```
SELECT id FROM photos WHERE id IN (SELECT photo_id, COUNT(*) ... )
```

запрос перестает работать, т.к. в данном случае, IN необходима одна колонка, а не две.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.photo_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM photos p, tags_rel t
WHERE p.id = t.photo_id
  AND t.tag_id in ( SELECT id 
                    FROM tags 
                    WHERE tag_name IN ('man', 'riding', 'horse')
                  ) 
GROUP BY t.photo_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

В принципе я бы и от второго IN рекомендовал избавиться аналогичным образом.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Пойду дальше читать :)